# Marshaling an array of structs with `char` array fields in F#

Tags: .net, f#, pinvoke, dllimport

The [Csound API](https://csound.com/docs/api/index.html) defines the [following `CS_AUDIODEVICE` struct](https://csound.com/docs/api/structCS__AUDIODEVICE.html):

```c
   typedef struct {
     char device_name[64];
     char device_id[64];
     char rt_module[64];
     int max_nchnls;
     int isOutput;
   } CS_AUDIODEVICE;
```

Then there is an API function called [`csoundGetAudioDevList`](https://csound.com/docs/api/group__RTAUDIOIO.html#ga697a4689253587e465131a7c037ffd74):

```c
PUBLIC int csoundGetAudioDevList(
    CSOUND* csound,
    CS_AUDIODEVICE* list,
    int isOutput
)
```

that is usually called twice. The first time, a null pointer is passed in to get the number of devices. Then the second time, a pointer sized to number of devices times the size of `CS_AUDIODEVICE` is passed in to get the actual array of devices.

I have struggled mightily to define my `DLLImport` declaration and get this data marshalled correctly.

In F#, the opaque struct `Csound` is defined as:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type CSOUND = struct end
```

This works fine.

---

##### Attempt 1

```ml
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type CS_AUDIODEVICE =
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)>]
    val device_name: string // char[64]
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)>]
    val device_id:   string // char[64]
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)>]
    val rt_module:   string // char[64]
    val max_nchnls:  int
    val isOutput:    int

[<DllImport(csoundDLLPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int csoundGetAudioDevList(CSOUND* csound, CS_AUDIODEVICE[] devices, int isOutput)

let numberOfDevices = csoundGetAudioDevList(csound, [||], 1)
let mutable devices = [| for _ in 1..numberOfDevices -> CS_AUDIODEVICE() |]
csoundGetAudioDevList(csound, devices, 1) |> ignore
devices
```

According to [Microsoft's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-different-types-of-arrays#declaring-prototypes) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759368/17800932 this should just work, but it doesn't. It crashes. I don't know what it crashes, as I just get `Session termination detected` in FSI (F# interactive).

---

##### Attempt 2

I tried redefining my struct:

```ml
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type CS_AUDIODEVICE =
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)>]
    val device_name: char[] // char[64]
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)>]
    val device_id:   char[] // char[64]
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)>]
    val rt_module:   char[] // char[64]
    val max_nchnls:  int
    val isOutput:    int
```

The rest of the setup is the same. And the result is the same in that this crashes.

---

##### Attempt 3

In the past, when I have had difficult marshaling things in a straightforward way, I have usually turned to `IntPtr`. I tried variations of

```ml
[<DllImport(csoundDLLPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int csoundGetAudioDevList(CSOUND* csound, IntPtr devices, int isOutput)

let numberOfDevices = csoundGetAudioDevList(csound, IntPtr.Zero, 1)
let mutable pointer = IntPtr(numberOfDevices * Marshal.SizeOf(CS_AUDIODEVICE))
let mutable devices = [| for _ in 1..numberOfDevices -> CS_AUDIODEVICE() |]
Marshal.StructureToPtr(devices, pointer, true)
csoundGetAudioDevList(csound, pointer, 1) |> ignore
//for i in 1..numberOfDevices do
//    devices[i-1] <- Marshal.PtrToStructure<CS_AUDIODEVICE>(pointer)
//    pointer <- IntPtr.Add(pointer, Marshal.SizeOf<CS_AUDIODEVICE>())
devices <- Marshal.PtrToStructure<CS_AUDIODEVICE[]>(pointer)
devices
```

I was trying to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/27483917/17800932 here plus things I have done before.

---

I simply cannot figure this out. Most things just silently crash, some things return stack traces that I can't understand, and some things even explicitly crash the CLR.

One frustration I have is that I cannot find a way to simply reason about this and read documentation on .NET and/or Csound's API. I do not have control over the API, only the documentation I linked above, so I can't just modify the function in the DLL that I am trying to call.

In my experience with these DLL bindings is that things that *should* work don't always, and I have found that with `DLLImport` stuff, I just gotta try sensible things and eventually get something working. So any explanations that not only provide something that works but explains why/how would be super appreciated!

Main questions:

1. How should the `CS_AUDIODEVICE` struct be defined?
2. What is the proper `DLLImport` declaration of the `csoundGetAudioDevList` function?
3. How do I marshal the list of audio devices out of the DLL?
4. Why/how does this all work?

Thank you!

---

Here is the rest of the code if you want to try and actually reproduce this. You need the Csound API. On Windows, it is located at `Csound-6.18.1-windows-x64-binaries\build\Release\csound64.dll` in the Windows binaries download.

```ml
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<Literal>]
let csoundDLLPath = @"<path to Csound DLL>"

[<Struct>]
type CSOUND = struct end

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type CS_AUDIODEVICE = ???

[<DllImport(csoundDLLPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern CSOUND* csoundCreate()

[<DllImport(csoundDLLPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int csoundStart(CSOUND* csound)

[<DllImport(csoundDLLPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int csoundSetOption(CSOUND* csound, string option)

[<DllImport(csoundDLLPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int csoundGetAudioDevList(CSOUND* csound, ???, int isOutput)

let c = csoundCreate()
csoundSetOption(c, "-odac") // this enables using the system's audio devices as the Csound output device
csoundStart c
// This is where csoundGetAudioDevList would be called
```

Comment: In C language `char` is 1-byte, while in dotnet `char` is 2-byte. Maybe it's the problem? Try to change constant size from 64 to 32

Comment: I tried Attempt 1 in a console app and it ran without crashing, but listed no devices. Have you tried running a console app instead of F# interactive?

Comment: Note: in C# `CS_AUDIODEVICE` can be declared in following way: https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMB0BKBXAdgFwJYFsCmsCSa2ATgPYAOAysQG7oDG2AzgNwCwAUBwNoWpGJ1UAGQCGATxKJUAClESpAaXTIAJrCoBHRNjToRAGwCUAXQ4gAzBBSMRAM2wRGfAaggBhCgH0AggFUAIngA8v4AogBqeG6hHADeHBCJEAD0yRAARth0IoiMDm4A5IwQdAAWIkQQ6MXQGWKo2AA0EADupej6DglJFhC26AAe2Cp1DRAq2LQMnsgiOFwAbAAsxmzsSVCW/UMj6fUOE1PYnugqiytrG73bw6MORKiemCQqiJ3nq92JvcqumCIDGZlZD6FhfTZVNBVRhBKRkKRrAC+HCAA==

Comment: Does int in this particular C and int in C# have the same size? (Try with int16 too.) Is Pack needed in StructLayout? Is the size of your struct what you expect? Is Cdecl the correct convention?

Comment: `[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)>]` That will automatically make it 1-byte characters. You don't need to specify `Pack`, and you don't neeed to change `SizeConst=64` to `32`

Comment: I will circle back on people's advice here and try things out, but as a quick note, simply setting `CharSet=CharSet.Ansi` in attempt 1 or 2 is actually the use case that crashes the CLR.

Comment: It turns out that there was an error in the Csound API documentation in terms of the size of the `char` arrays. (They are actually 128 and not 64.) I've posted a solution that works in addition to @tranquillity's working solution. Lastly, @Charlieface, why was the `c#` tag edited out? Ths seems as relevant as anything to C#. The same issues exist in either language, and the bindings and calling examples are usually just translations of each other.

Comment: You should really only tag one language if that's what you're working in, because people need to know what language to answer the question in. People will still be able to find this if they are searching for CSound. I stand by what I said: if you want to use `string` and `UnmanagedType.ByValTStr` you need `CharSet.Ansi` but obviously if the length is wrong you will have problems.

Comment: I think this is more of a case of .NET rather than a particular .NET language. These bindings are basically defined identically between C# and F#, sans some specific syntax somewhat irrelevant to the overall approach. So I see this as not specific to Csound but rather "how do I correctly marshal data in .NET with `DllImport` and `extern` declarations for a specific type of struct and function definition?". I juse happen to be using F#.

That's a good point about the `CharSet`. I simply forgot it in my updated solution since I was working backwards from using `byte`. I added it there.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments the following should work to declare the struct from C#:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct CS_AUDIODEVICE
{
    public fixed byte device_name[64];
    public fixed byte device_id[64];
    public fixed byte rt_module[64];
    public int max_nchnls;
    public int isOutput;
}
```

Unfortunately, F# doesn't support the `fixed` syntax for declaring inline buffers. Instead, we can do:

```ml
#nowarn "9"
#nowarn "51"

open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
open Microsoft.FSharp.NativeInterop
        
type CSOUND = struct end

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 64)>]
type Byte64 =
    val mutable first: byte

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type CS_AUDIODEVICE =
    [<FixedBuffer(typeof<byte>, 64)>]
    val mutable device_name: Byte64
    [<FixedBuffer(typeof<byte>, 64)>]
    val mutable device_id: Byte64
    [<FixedBuffer(typeof<byte>, 64)>]
    val mutable rt_module: Byte64
    val mutable max_nchnls: int
    val mutable isOutput: int

[<DllImport("csoundDLLPath", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int csoundGetAudioDevList(CSOUND* csound, CS_AUDIODEVICE* devices, int isOutput)

let writeExample () =
    let mutable x = CS_AUDIODEVICE()
    let addr = &&x.device_name.first
    let span = Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr addr, 64)
    span[0] <- byte 'a'
    span[1] <- byte 'b'
    span[2] <- 0uy

    printfn "%s" (Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi (NativePtr.toNativeInt addr))

    
let callExample () =
    let xs = GC.AllocateArray<CS_AUDIODEVICE>(3, pinned = true) // Array must be pinned at allocation or with a GCHandle
    let mutable csound = CSOUND()
    let code = csoundGetAudioDevList(&&csound, &&xs[0], 0)
    code
```

We have to coerce the field addresses into a `VoidPtr` then we can use `Span` as a way to access the reserved bytes. Allocating a `pinned` array allows us to pass in the address to the native function.

Attempting to do this without first pinning the memory will likely crash or corrupt the program. Structs allocated with `let mutable` will live on the stack and it is safe to take their address while they are in scope.

Edit (Additional Explanation):

`FixedBuffer` isn't necessary but is emitted by the C# version (as seen when decompiling with [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4B0ASgK4B2ALgJYC2MlAkkzFBAA4BlXgDdmYGAGcA3IUIBtQYyi0wjADIBDAJ4RajABRbd+gNLN6AE0rCAjrRhNmmgDYBKALqEMAZlINJTQAzGFJJZVVGUgBhQQB9AEEAVQARTgB5FIBRADVOaKzCAG9CUjLyPyDmBBhLUmBtRlDLGDEJOPpNdnlUD1kCcorSKpq6hqbSFraYOOZLHpQ+0vLfYera+sbQqEY41ghLWhcYBaWBlb8LKNZNBA6wAAt6FxllstWr0mZJdP1+fX6AF8gA===)). I didn't test it but it should allow C# consumers to treat `Byte64` as a `byte[]`.

`MarshalAs` attributes cause the compiler to generate extra marshaling code behind the scenes to convert the .NET type into a native compatible type. The way it is done with `Byte64` the struct is `unmanaged` [ref1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints#remarks) [ref2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types) and no additional marshaling code is needed.

`Span` isn't strictly necessary and you can freely convert between `IntPtr` and `nativeptr<_>` using the [NativePtr module functions](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-nativeinterop-nativeptrmodule.html). This module gives you ways to do pointer manipulation directly. `IntPtr.Zero` is equivalent to `NativePtr.nullPtr` and `nativeptr<_>` gets erased to `IntPtr` by the F# compiler.

Comment: Thanks! A couple of questions. (1) Why is `FixedBuffer` needed and what does it do differently than `[<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)>] val device_name: byte[]`? (2) Is there a way to make this work with `IntPtr` instead of using `NativePtr` and `Span`? When I use `IntPtr`, I can get the number of devices just fine by passing in `IntPtr.Zero` for a null pointer, but I get crashes of `Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.` when trying to get the devices.

Comment: I've added some additional explanations. If you're still getting `AccessViolationException` there's likely something else wrong with the pointer arithmetic. This kind of code is very error-prone and I tend to write lots of tests and helper functions to ensure all the bytes are laid out correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much! And yes, this stuff is quite delicate with not great documentation from Microsoft and somewhat reliant upon the DLL to behave expectedly. I will give this another try. Also, F# does have a `fixed` keyword which can "fix" a value and return a `nativeptr`. I tried doing something similar to what you did by using `fixed` on an array of `CS_AUDIODEVICE`s and then marshaling it similar to what you did with `Span`, but it didn't work, even though the size (in bytes) of the array is what I would expect (bytes per struct = 196 = 3*64 + 2 + 2).

Comment: Thanks again for the help! I finally got this going. The primary problem was that the Csound API documentation is out of date. :( I still wasn't getting any solution, including yours, working, but at least yours was returning *some* data and not crashing. After that, I inspected the Python bindings for the Csound API, which is in the Csound repository, whereby I discovered that the size of the `char` arrays is actually 128 and not 64. Your solution now works perfectly. I'm going to play around with it and see if I can't simplify it to where some of the marshaling is handled more automatically.

Comment: Thanks once more for the help and solution! I played around a bit more after figuring out the documentation error and having your solution to go off of and came up with another solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice work! What a frustrating problem that the docs don't match the code

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that one of the main issues in figuring all of this out properly is that the Csound API documentation is out of date. If we view the [`CS_AUDIODEVICE` struct in the API documentation](https://csound.com/docs/api/structCS__AUDIODEVICE.html), then we see that the `char` arrays are of length 64. However, if we navigate to the [Csound repository, the header lists the arrays in `CS_AUDIODEVICE` as length 128](https://github.com/csound/csound/blob/a1580f9cdf331c35dceb486f4231871ce0b00266/include/csound.h#L527-L533). This is unfortunate, since it means I and others here were spinning wheels on something that couldn't possibly work due to the documentation error.

Thankfully, due to @tranquillity's answer, I was able to get some actual data back with their method (instead of just crashes) and noticed that the data was incomplete. I then looked up the [Python Csound API bindings, which happen to be in the Csound repository itself](https://github.com/csound/csound/blob/a1580f9cdf331c35dceb486f4231871ce0b00266/interfaces/ctcsound.py#L92-L97), which is where I saw the 128 length and then confirmed it in the `csound.h` header file.

Since there are a lot of the structures like this in the Csound API, I am wanting something a bit more straightforward, so I played around a bit and come up with:

```ml
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<Struct>]
type CSOUND = struct end

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)>]
type CS_AUDIODEVICE =
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)>]
    val device_name: string // char[128]
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)>]
    val device_id:   string // char[128]
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)>]
    val rt_module:   string // char[128]
    val max_nchnls:  int
    val isOutput:    int

[<DllImport(csoundDLLPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int csoundGetAudioDevList(CSOUND* csound, IntPtr devices, int isOutput)

let marshalIntPtrToStructures<'Structure> (pointer: IntPtr, numberOfStructures) =
    let mutable pointer = pointer
    [| for _ in 1..numberOfStructures ->
        let structure = Marshal.PtrToStructure<'Structure>(pointer)
        pointer <- IntPtr.Add(pointer, Marshal.SizeOf<'Structure>())
        structure |]

let initializeIntPtrFromStructures<'Structure> numberOfStructures: IntPtr =
    Marshal.AllocHGlobal(numberOfStructures * Marshal.SizeOf<CS_AUDIODEVICE>())

let getAudioDeviceOutputs (Csound csound) =
    printfn "Size of CS_AUDIODEVICE: %A" (Marshal.SizeOf<CS_AUDIODEVICE>())

    let numberOfDevices = csoundGetAudioDevList(csound, IntPtr.Zero, 1)

    printfn "Number of devices: %A" numberOfDevices
    
    let pointer = initializeIntPtrFromStructures<CS_AUDIODEVICE> numberOfDevices

    csoundGetAudioDevList(csound, pointer, 1) |> ignore

    let devices =  marshalIntPtrToStructures<CS_AUDIODEVICE>(pointer, numberOfDevices)

    for device in devices do
        printfn "Name: %A, ID: %A" device.device_name device.device_id
```

The `printfn` statements are there to confirm the values are what I expect. This all works now! And this should be generally reusable across the several structs in the Csound API (I hope). It also allows me to define the struct in a more straightforward way and makes it easier to marshal out the fields once I have the array of structs in hand.

What I am still curious about though is if there is a better and/or built-in way to do what the `marshalIntPtrToStructures` and `initializeIntPtrFromStructures` are doing. It seems kind of strange that there isn't, at least I couldn't find them, especially for `marshalIntPtrToStructures`. From what I have seen, you cannot use the built-in `Marshal.PtrToStructure` on an array. I was getting unsupported type exceptions like: `System.MissingMethodException: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'FSI_0028.Csound.Native+CS_AUDIODEVICE[]'. Reason: Type is not supported.` (I *think* that is the right exception from when I tried that).

---

A final note. Microsoft has documentation for marshaling arrays and structs here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-classes-structures-and-unions#structures-sample
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-different-types-of-arrays

The problem with those methods is that the `csoundGetAudioDevList` is a bit weird and requires a null pointer to be passed in to first get the number of audio devices. Then you call it again with a properly constructed pointer to get the actual devices. With the methods described in the two bullets above, there is no way to pass in a null pointer with the way that the prototypes are declared, as far as I can tell. Those methods are the easiest since they defer a lot of the marshaling (to the CLR, I guess), but they don't work for an unmanaged function like `csoundGetAudioDevList` that also requires use of a null pointer.